# How do I put a specific integer into the middle of a sorted array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I am writing code where five random numbers are given a value.  Those five values are then sorted in an array in numerical order.  However, when one value is equaled to 1, I want that number to be in the middle of the sorted array.

When there is no number 1, the sorted array will work correctly.

```
let fourthRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))
let fifthRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))
let sixthRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))
let seventhRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))
let eighthRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))

var loFourthRandomNumberOutput: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1]
var loFifthRandomNumberOutput: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1]
var loSixthRandomNumberOutput: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1]
var loSeventhRandomNumberOutput: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1]
var loEighthRandomNumberOutput: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1]

var hiFourthRandomNumberOutput: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11]
var hiFifthRandomNumberOutput: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11]
var hiSixthRandomNumberOutput: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11]
var hiSeventhRandomNumberOutput: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11]
var hiEighthRandomNumberOutput: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11]



let loFourthRandomNumber:Int = loFourthRandomNumberOutput [fourthRandomNumber]
let loFifthRandomNumber:Int = loFifthRandomNumberOutput [fifthRandomNumber]
let loSixthRandomNumber:Int = loSixthRandomNumberOutput [sixthRandomNumber]
let loSeventhRandomNumber:Int = loSeventhRandomNumberOutput [seventhRandomNumber]
let loEighthRandomNumber:Int = loEighthRandomNumberOutput [eighthRandomNumber]

let hiFourthRandomNumber:Int = hiFourthRandomNumberOutput [fourthRandomNumber]
let hiFifthRandomNumber:Int = hiFifthRandomNumberOutput [fifthRandomNumber]
let hiSixthRandomNumber:Int = hiSixthRandomNumberOutput [sixthRandomNumber]
let hiSeventhRandomNumber:Int = hiSeventhRandomNumberOutput [seventhRandomNumber]
let hiEighthRandomNumber:Int = hiEighthRandomNumberOutput [eighthRandomNumber]

//NEED TO WORK OUT THIS ISSUE  **(add ace)**
var loDealerCardsArray = [loFourthRandomNumberOutput [fourthRandomNumber], loFifthRandomNumberOutput [fifthRandomNumber], loSixthRandomNumberOutput [sixthRandomNumber], loSeventhRandomNumberOutput [seventhRandomNumber], loEighthRandomNumberOutput [eighthRandomNumber]]

//NEED TO WORK OUT THIS ISSUE  **(add ace)**
var hiDealerCardsArray = [hiFourthRandomNumberOutput [fourthRandomNumber], hiFifthRandomNumberOutput [fifthRandomNumber], hiSixthRandomNumberOutput [sixthRandomNumber], hiSeventhRandomNumberOutput [seventhRandomNumber], hiEighthRandomNumberOutput [eighthRandomNumber]]

loDealerCardsArray.sort()

loDealerCardsArray[0]
loDealerCardsArray[1]
loDealerCardsArray[2]

print (loDealerCardsArray[0] + loDealerCardsArray[1] + loDealerCardsArray[2])

//NEED TO WORK OUT THIS ISSUE **(PULL IN RANDOM NUMBER FROM ARRAY SO THAT CARD APPEARS IN PROPER LOCATION when there is an ace


hiDealerCardsArray.sort()

hiDealerCardsArray[2]
hiDealerCardsArray[3]
hiDealerCardsArray[4]

print (hiDealerCardsArray[2] + hiDealerCardsArray[3] + hiDealerCardsArray[4])

////NEED TO WORK OUT THIS ISSUE **(PULL IN RANDOM NUMBER FROM ARRAY SO THAT CARD APPEARS IN PROPER LOCATION when there is an ace

var DealerCardsArray = [fourthRandomNumber, fifthRandomNumber, sixthRandomNumber, seventhRandomNumber, eighthRandomNumber]

DealerCardsArray.sort()
DealerCardsArray[0]
DealerCardsArray[1]
DealerCardsArray[2]
DealerCardsArray[3]
DealerCardsArray[4]
```

For example, five cards have a value of [0, 1, 2, 9, 10], and the array is sorted correctly.  I am trying to sort the array so that the 1 is ALWAYS in the middle.

When an ace (value of 1 or 11) appears in the sorted array I want it to look as follows:  [0, 2, 1, 9, 10]

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var dealerCardsArray = [0, 1, 2, 9, 10]

dealerCardsArray.sort()

// Only if the value 1 exists in the array, remove it and add it back in the center position
if let indexOfOne = dealerCardsArray.index(of: 1) {
    dealerCardsArray.remove(at: indexOfOne)
    dealerCardsArray.insert(1, at: array.count/2)
}

print(dealerCardsArray) // [0,2,1,9,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var cards = [0, 1, 2, 9, 10]

// Get a list of all the aces in the array.
let aces = cards.filter { $0 == 1  || $0 == 11 }

// Now take the aces out of the array.
cards = cards.filter { $0 != 1 && $0 != 11 }

// Sort the array (unnecessary if its definitely already sorted).
cards = cards.sort()

// Re-insert the aces into the middle.
aces.forEach { cards.insert($0, atIndex: cards.count/2) }

// [0, 2, 1, 9, 10]
```

Might do the trick (haha)!